# This is a bill of the food vs. This is the bill of the food

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

> 1. This is the bill of the food I ate last night.
> 2. This is a bill of the food I ate last night.

According to me, **#1** suggests that we are talking about just 1 specific bill. Whereas, I think, but not sure, **#2** might suggest that there are other bills of the food and we are talking about one of those bills.

Are my interpretations correct, or I am missing something, does it mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually talk about the bill **for** something. Otherwise, your interpretations are correct. We would use the definite article ('the') for **the** only bill, and the indefinite article ('a') for **a** bill which is, or could be, one of a number.